# Advanced Checkboxes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I have a form that is a table built with php to pull a bunch of information from the database.  In these, i have a checkbox that, when clicked, pulls the value of the estimatedCost and throws it into a JavaScript function that calculates it and keeps a running total of all the objects checked.

What i'm trying to do is create a check all and uncheck all option that will still pass the needed variables into the other javascript functions.  Let me demonstrate with some code:

This draws the checkbox next to the title.

```php
foreach($replace as $key => $value)
  {
    $jScript = 'onclick=\'calcTotals("'.$replace[$key]['estimatedCost'].'","'.$replace[$key]['optionItem_id_replaceOrRepair'].'","'.$replace[$key]['service_title'].'","'.$replace[$key]['maintenanceitem_id'].'");\'';
    $checkbox = sprintf('<input type="checkBox" name="ids[]" id="%s" value="%s" %s>', $replace[$key]['maintenanceitem_id'], $replace[$key]['maintenanceitem_id'], $jScript).'&nbsp;';
    $replace[$key]['title'] = $checkbox.$replace[$key]['title'];
    $replace[$key]['estimatedCost'] =  $replace[$key]['estimatedCost'];
  }
```

This is the current check all and uncheck all links:

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick=\'setCheckboxes("budgeting", true); return false;\'>Check All</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
  echo '<a href="#" onClick=\'setCheckboxes("budgeting", false); return false;\'>Uncheck All</a>';
```

Now the current functions i have in javascript:

```
function setBudgetCheckboxes(the_form, do_check) {
        var elts      = (typeof(document.forms[the_form].elements['ids[]']) != 'undefined')
                      ? document.forms[the_form].elements['ids[]']
                      : (typeof(document.forms[the_form].elements['ids[]']) != 'undefined')
              ? document.forms[the_form].elements['ids[]']
              : document.forms[the_form].elements['ids[]'];
        var elts_cnt  = (typeof(elts.length) != 'undefined')
                      ? elts.length
                      : 0;
        if (elts_cnt) {
            for (var i = 0; i < elts_cnt; i++) {
                elts[i].checked = do_check;
                var name = document.getElementById(name);
            } // end for
        } else {
            elts.checked = do_check;
        } // end if... else
        return true;
    }
```

And the other, which handles the clicks one at a time:

```
function calcTotals(amount, type, service, name) {
        if(amount[0] == '$') {
            amount = amount.substr(1,amount.length);
        }
        var id = type+"_"+service+"_selected";
        var grand_id = "Grand_selected";
        var grand_service_id = "Grand_"+service+"_selected";
        var type_id = type+"_selected";

        var checked = document.getElementById(name).checked;

        var multiplier = -1;

        if(checked) {
            multiplier = 1;
        }

        amount = amount * multiplier;

        addBudgetValue(amount, id);
        addBudgetValue(amount, grand_id);
        addBudgetValue(amount, grand_id+"_h");
        addBudgetValue(amount, type_id);
        addBudgetValue(amount, grand_service_id);
        addBudgetValue(amount, grand_service_id+"_h");
    }
function addBudgetValue(amount, id) {
        var current_value = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
        var curtmp = 0;
        if(current_value == "$0") {
            current_value = amount;
        }
        else {
            curtmp = parseFloat(current_value.substr(1,current_value.length));
            current_value = (curtmp+parseFloat(amount));
        }   
        var newVal = "$"+Number(current_value).toFixed(2);
        if(newVal == "$0.00")
            newVal = "$0";  
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newVal;
    }
```

So the question is this: How do you get the check all to check all the boxes, and pass the information into the calcTotals function so that the values are added correctly?

Comment: Rather than interpret all of the foregoing code manually, could you make it easier on us by describing the behaviour you're seeing from your current 'check all' method?  And are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: When you select a check box one at a time, it adds the value estimatedCost to the current running cost and displays it in a floating table on the page.  It'll go up and down depending on selecting and unselecting items.  The check all link will check all the boxes, but won't add up all the costs. (As a side effect, you can manually unselect a checkbox and the cost starts to go negative.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle that does what (I think) you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/kz9gU/1/

I'm using a custom `data-*` attribute to store the estimated cost (spec compliant as per HTML5), so it's defined in the checkboxes' tags. Each checkbox then calls an `updateTotal()` function when checked/unchecked, but doesn't pass any arguments. `updateTotal()` then loops through the checkboxes, reading each amount from the `data-cost` attribute, and displays the sum.

The check/uncheck functions then don't need to calculate any values; they just check/uncheck everything and call `updateTotal()` afterwards.

Edit: Heh, just realized you're not using jQuery. I'm just starting to take jQuery for granted, even though I actually don't use jQuery myself. What you see in the fiddle is probably the longest piece of jQuery-based JS, I've actually written :)
At any rate, it's almost always a good idea to use some sort of library to smooth out browser differences, and jQuery is king of the heap right now.

But library or not, the code should give you an idea of how you could proceed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s8L2M/2/ - This one handles negative and decimal values, and doesn't bind click handlers to the markup. ;)

Comment: These both are really helpful, but would be better if it was JavaScript instead, as i'm not real familiar with jQuery at all.  Thanks for helping with the logic behind it though!

Comment: @TeslaNick: Yeah, I wouldn't `onclick` attribute either, but I didn't want to change _all_ of OP's original code around :) --- but you're right, it's not pretty to have the handlers in markup. BTW, mine should handle negative values just fine, but for decimal values, it's best to avoid using floats for prices. Rather multiply everything by 100 to get cents, and then divide by 100 when needed. You won't risk any funky floating point issues that way. I updated the fiddle earlier with a comment about that.

Comment: @IceBlueFire: Well, it _is_ javascript, there's just a library involved :) --- but the basic premise of my solution is that you put the estimated cost in the html, somewhere, and then use a js function to get it from the html, rather than the html passing it to the function. That can be done in "pure" js too, but browser differences could ruin your day quickly. So, I'd still say use a library of some kind to help you out.

Comment: @Flambino: The bugs in Javascript's floating point math only become apparent for very precise numbers. `Number.toFixed(2)` should wipe out any number inconsistencies on that front. Still, they are both valid approaches. I was about to put together an answer that worked exactly like yours when I saw yours pop up, no reason to rewrite the wheel. :)

Comment: @IceBlueFire: Here's a pure javascript version of the same solution. It does DOM1-style click binding, which makes me unhappy, but it gets the job done without a normalization library: http://jsfiddle.net/s8L2M/3/

Comment: @TeslaNick: True, the floating point madness shouldn't be a problem in this case, but if you start considering things like X% discounts, sales taxes or strange bulk purchase discount calculations and whatnot, _and_ you have a long list of numbers to crunch, it doesn't take much to make everything get real funky, real quick. So as a precaution I always put prices on a cent basis in both backend and frontend

Comment: @Flambino: If you start diving into that kind of stuff, you're in for a world of hurt (trust me, I've tried). You're way better off writing an ajax service that asks the server, "If the user purchases these SKUs with these coupon codes, and these discounts, what would the total be?" That way you only need to implement your pricing logic once. ;)

Comment: @TeslaNick: Oh, totally. Except the trouble was that the backend of the site that first got me doing all this also had some funky floating point issues from time to time (hence integer amounts in the database and everywhere else). Since then I've been paranoid about it :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you currectly, you want a check/uncheck all feature? http://jetlogs.org/jquery/jquery_select_all.html after that get the checkbox array with php and pass the information, in PHP do a loop to check the values of the array and execute your statements.

Comment: I have to be able to do it without ever changing pages.  There is a floating table on the page that displays the running total.

Comment: oh like submitting results with page refresh?

Comment: Uh, kinda.  If you look at where the checkbox is declared, it defines it's own javascript function that passes in the variable $estimatedCost, which is the variable i'm having issues getting at with the check all button.